# Role of „euer selbst“ in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun

In a recent [Linguee search](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=Und%20ihr%20werdet%20als%20erstes%20euer%20selbst%20finden%20oder%20erkennen.), the following sentence appeared:

> Und ihr werdet als erstes **euer Selbst** finden oder erkennen.

I am not sure the form and role of *euer selbst*.  My guess is that *euer Selbst* is the reflexive pronoun of *ihr* in the genitive.  This seems wrong as *finden* would need an accusative object – i.e. *euch*.

Comment: Very, very likely, the lower-case *selbst* is wrong. You might want to uppercase it, and then look up the **Substantive** in a dictionary.

Comment: Could also, less likely, be supposed to be "euch selbst". In the current form the sentence looks wrong.

Comment: @tofro - Indeed *selbst* is capitalized in LInguee and the possessive of *das Selbst* in the accusative = *euer Selbst* now seems very likely! Could you please promote your comment to a reply so it can be voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Selbst", when capitalized (in German capitalization really *really* matters) is a *Nomen*, meaning "(inner) self". It is neuter, btw., so "das Selbst".

"Euer" is a *Possessivpronomen*, in this case the *Akkusativ* *Plural* of "euch". In this case it means "your".

The whole sentence translated would be:

> Und ihr werdet als erstes euer Selbst finden oder erkennen.
> And you will, first thing, find or identify *your self*.